# Php echo random User from DB

Tags: php, sql, database, random

I trying to echo a random User from my database:
I got this so far:

```
$randUser = "SELECT * FROM `staff` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
echo $randUser;
```

But this just does output me my sql string.
How to solve this issue.

Comment: You should read how to use SQL with PHP!!

Comment: Try doing a basic tutorial first. What you're currently doing is echoing out a string. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not connected to any database yet.
You only stored the query string in the $randUser variable.

Here's a sample of code :

```
$database = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
foreach($database->query('SELECT * FROM `staff` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1') as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

But you should consider reading the documentation first : http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Answer (score 1):

That's because you don't execute your query!
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
is one of the simplest ways to do this. But you really should consider reading a php DB tutorial first!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are echoing the string as it is. Here's what you need to do

```
<? mysql_connect('your_host', 'Your_username', 'your_password');
mysql_select_db('your_databasename');

$randUser = "SELECT * FROM `staff` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($randUsrr);
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  echo $user['colname'];
}

?>
```

Note: Replace your_host, your_username, your_password and colname with respective actual values.

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_` functions for everything. It's going away in PHP 7. MySQLi and PDO should be used instead.